# How to stream a WPF window content to another computer

Tags: wpf, windows, streaming

Does anyone know how a WPF window's view area can be streamed to remote computers? e.g. Can someone use a web browser and point to an address whereby this address shows the content of this WPF application?

This is somewhat like maybe desktop sharing but just over a small estate, which is the window's viewable area.

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't really explain what exactly you trying to accomplish which makes it hard to understand.

"Streaming" the content of window comes in a few flavors and has limited uses. 
Typically its way more efficient to share data not how it presented. That said here are some common ones.

For example [Cicso's WebEx](http://www.webex.com/) allows you to share your desktop or a single application in the context of a conference call.

[Citrix XenApp](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=186) allows you to deliver an applicaiton to a client that's installed on the server (thin client).

You could also use Windows Media Encoder (which has an SDK) to capture an encode the contents of an application. However this is usually done as part of a demonstation and not in a "live context"